# Why doesn't md-grid-list generate from HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send a HTTP request to get a JSON and generate md-grid-list according to it. But it does not seem to work.

I write that request in my controller.

If I replace md-grid-list with other normal elements such as table and td, etc, it would work. Or if I load another normal element depending on that JSON somewhere else, for example even plain text like {{posterPlaying.posters}}, it would also work.

How come is it? It seems that it must be some peculiar properties of md-grid-list.

HTML:

```
<md-content layout="row" ng-controller="posterPlayingController as posterPlaying" id="poster-page">

    <md-content layout="column" id="poster-container">
        <md-grid-list
            md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="4" md-cols-gt-md="6"
            md-row-height-gt-md="2:3" md-row-height="2:3"
            md-gutter="8px" md-gutter-gt-sm="4px" >
            <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="poster in posterPlaying.posters"
                          md-rowspan="{{poster.span.row}}"
                          md-colspan="{{poster.span.col}}"
                          md-colspan-sm="1"
                          ng-class="poster.background" >
                <md-button aria-label="" class="poster-button" ng-click="showVote($event)">

                      <img src="{{poster.image}}" class="md-card-image poster-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
                </md-button>
            </md-grid-tile>
      </md-grid-list>
</md-content>
```

services.js

```
(function (angular, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module('services', ['ngResource'])
        .factory('Poster', Poster);

    Poster.$inject = ['$resource'];
    function Poster($resource) {
        return $resource('data/posters.json', {}, {
            query: {
                method: "get",
                params: {},
                isArray: true
            }
        })
    }
})(angular);
```

Inside posterPlayingController

```
vm.posters = Poster.query(function (response) {
            var data = response.map(function (item, index, array) {
                item.position = item.id % 2;
                if (item.id % 5 == 0) {
                    item.span = {
                        'row': 2,
                        'col': 2
                    }
                } else {
                    item.span = {
                        'row': 1,
                        'col': 1
                    }
                }
                return item;
            });
            return data;
        });
```

Comment: can you post the code you have been trying so we can help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in how you pass the success function in the `query` method. The `query` method expects these arguments:`Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])` So you should use `Poster.query(null, function () {})` or `Poster.query().$promise.then(function() {})`

So this question is not much about mdGridList as it is about resource.

Also not that the `query` method is automatically included in `$resource` by default so you do not need to add it when calling `$resource()`.